# Have there been any hits from the Vatican?

Tags: discussion

I was just about to make a dumb joke about the Pope using this site to determine whether deaconesses were a good idea and then realized this might actually be true.

Do we have any stats to tell whether the Pope (or anyone with a vatican.va TLD) has hit our website?

Answer (score 3):

I took a look through the mod tools and the closest thing I saw was a list of referral sites, which identify only the middle-man and not the user. As far as I know, external websites such as Quantcast only count visits and don't keep track of where visitors are connecting from. Thus, I think the only way to get such information would be to get a dev or other Stack Exchange employee to take a look at their logs, which I *think* is ethically, legally, *and* technically infeasible. I don't even know if they actually log the source of every visit.

So, I guess your only recourse is to ask Jon Ericson (or another community manager) and/or the Pope himself.

Comment: @sandwich - oh, I forgot that they can track that stuff too. That's probably the best resource we've got.

Comment: @sandwich That would make a good answer.